# 4th level subdomain redirect without changing the URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Please excuse me and my near-to-zero apache skills. I'm an owner of a website and I would love to redirect my fourth level domains (for example fyz.edu.ondrejaugusta.cz, che.edu.ondrejaugusta.cz etc.) to a directory /subdomains/fyz, /subdomains/che respectively.
Also I would appreciate if the URL didn't change to ondrejaugusta.cz/subdomains/fyz (or /che) and stayed like fyz.edu.ondrejaugusta.cz.
I'm struggling to get it working for more than a week now - I've read a lot of articles, none of which (sadly) helped me. Please tell me what I'm supposed to do / change, I am clueless.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fyz\.edu\.ondrejaugusta\.cz$
RewriteRule ^ http://ondrejaugusta.cz/subdomains/fyz%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^che\.edu\.ondrejaugusta\.cz$
RewriteRule ^ http://ondrejaugusta.cz/subdomains/che%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```

This is the code I've got so far. It's working, but redirecting to /subdomains/fyz (/subdomains/che).
Also don't worry, I'm not teaching informatics or English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are actually looking for an internal rewrite and *not* for a redirection, since you ask the visible URL in the browser not to get altered.

This will internally rewrite any request to such a "4th level" host name to a folder in the local "subdomains" folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.edu\.ondrejaugusta\.cz$
RewriteRule ^ /subdomains/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module has to be loaded and enabled for those hosts, likewise the interpretation of such distributed configuration files (".htaccess") if you really want to rely on those.